# If $\{v_0,v_1\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$ form a basis for $\mathbb Z^2$ then $v_2=-v_0+a_1v_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading the section on non-singular surfaces from Fulton's book, *Introduction to Toric varieties*. There we have the following -

> Let $v_0,v_1,\dots,v_d=v_0$ be a sequence of lattice points in counterclockwise order (see figure below), in $\mathbb Z^2$, such that successive pairs generate $\mathbb Z^2$ as a $\mathbb Z$-module.
>
> [image]
>
> From the fact that $v_0$ and $v_1$ are a $\mathbb Z$-basis for $\mathbb Z^2$, and $v_1$ and $v_2$ are also a $\mathbb Z$-basis, we know that $v_2=-v_0+a_1v_1$ for some integer $a_1$. In general, we must have $$a_iv_i=v_{i-1}+v_{i+1}, \quad 1\leq i\leq d$$ for some integers $a_i$.

**Question** -

I do not understand how $\{v_0,v_1\}$ and $\{v_1,v_2\}$ being bases of $\mathbb Z^2$ imply $v_2=-v_0+a_1v_1$.

Since $v_0,v_1$ form a $\mathbb Z$-basis we can write $v_2=a_0v_0+a_1v_1$ for integers $a_0,a_1$. But I am not sure what to do next.

Thank you

Comment: Can you say what "counterclockwise order" means more precisely in this context?  This doesn't appear to be true for what I would think is the most obvious interpretation (that the given cyclic ordering of the $v_i$ agrees with the counterclockwise cyclic order).

Comment: @EricWofsey, I am sorry for the delay in editing. Counterclockwise order is in the sense of the figure above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that both $\{v_0, v_1\}$ and $\{v_1, v_2\}$ form a $\mathbf Z$-basis. Hence, the matrix of basis exchange, 
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_0\\
                       1 & a_1\end{pmatrix}
$$ where $v_2 = a_0v_0 + a_1v_1$ is invertible over $\mathbf Z$, that is $\det(M) \in \mathbf Z^\times = \{\pm 1\}$. As $\det(M) = -a_0$, we have that $a_0 \in \{\pm 1\}$. As $v_0, v_1,v_2$ are in counter-clockwise order, it follows that $a_0 = -1$, that is $v_2 = -v_0 + a_1v_1$.

Comment: Why does "counter-clockwise order" imply that $a_0=-1$ (and what is your definition of "counter-clockwise order")?